# If I have a select statement, how can I easily break that up into an insert statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
select * 
from 
  component 
inner join 
  component_supplier on component.id = component_supplier.component_id
inner join 
  supplier on supplier.id = component_supplier.supplier_id
where 
  component_supplier.supplier_part_no = ".048_CR_SHT_A1008_CS_TP_ B_4ftx8ft"
```

I want to take this data and chop it up and cram it into another table as so:

```
  INSERT into sugarcrm2.jce_components jce_c(   
    id,
    name,
    part_no_id,
    part_no,
    cost,
    lead,
    qty,   
    units,   
    class,   
    category,   
    notes ) 
  VALUES(   
    a bunch of different values that I get from that first select. 
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT can take the form:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(A,B,C) 
SELECT A, B, C 
FROM TABLE1 
INNER JOIN...
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally an "insert into table_x(field list) select from (your select statement) would be what you want.   You won't want to do a select * for this as the order of the fields needs to match up.

for example

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into sugarcrm2.jce_components jce_c(id,   name,
    part_no_id,   part_nocost,   lead,   qty,   units,   
    class,   category,   notes )
select component.id,   component.name,   component.part_no_id,   
    part_nocost,   lead,   qty,   units,   class,   category,   notes  
from    component  
    inner join    component_supplier on component.id = component_supplier.component_id 
    inner join    supplier on supplier.id = component_supplier.supplier_id 
where    component_supplier.supplier_part_no = ".048_CR_SHT_A1008_CS_TP_ B_4ftx8ft"
```

I don't know which values are in which table, but you have to do .column after the select.